# Convert Object<T> to Object<A> where A is contained in T

Tags: typescript, casting, type-conversion, prisma, prisma2

I'm working with Prisma to generate schemas and models for my database data.
There, I define a "User" model, which has this data (the type is automatically generated by Prisma):

```
type User {
    name: string,
    nickName: string,
    sensitiveInfo1: string,
    sensitiveInfo2: string
}
```

However, when my client requests this data, I can't send the sensitive info in the response payload.

Prisma has a very handy way for defining a custom type:

```
import { UserGetPayload } from "./prisma/src/generated/client"

// now I define a custom type
export type UserPublicInfo = UserGetPayload<{
    select: {
        name: true,
        nickName: true,
    }
}>

// this gives me the type:
// type UserPublicInfo {
//        name: <whatever type name is in the schema>,
//        nickName: <whatever type nickName is in the schema>
// }
```

Now, suppose I already have a user instance retrieved from the database, of type User. I wan't to cast it to "UserPublicInfo" in a way that the response payload only contains info of "UserPublicInfo".

If I cast an Object of type User like `user as UserPublicInfo` the type suggestions points to the right direction, showing only attributes of the subtype. However, the sensitive data still there.

I'm junior at javascipt/typescript but I believe this has something to do with the Object's prototype. So how can I cast it this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two pieces to this question, how to tell typescript that the properties are gone and how to actually remove them.

**Typescript**

What you are looking for are the typescript utilities [Pick](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys) and [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys).

To get only the fields `name` and `nickName` from `User`:

```
type UserPublicInfo = Pick<User, 'name' | 'nickName'>
```

To get all fields from `User` except for `sensitiveInfo1` and `sensitiveInfo2`:

```
type UserWithoutPrivate = Omit<User, 'sensitiveInfo1' | 'sensitiveInfo2'>
```

In the example you've given, both of these types are identical and resolve to

```
type UserPublicInfo = {
    name: string;
    nickName: string;
}
```

**Javascript**

Now for removing the properties.  The easiest thing is to use the `pick` and `omit` functions from the package [lodash](http://lodash.com/).  Those have built-in typescript support so you don't need to know about any of the TS stuff I just told you.

If you want to do it yourself, you can use the spread operator to drop the properties that you don't want (note: some linters will complain about unused variables here).

```
export const userToPublic = (user: User): UserPublicInfo => {
    const {sensitiveInfo1, sensitiveInfo2, ...rest} = user;
    return user;
}
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBT1AOwEMBbCALijmEQEsCBzAGh30NoGMBrAOVIqo16zVvgQE4tYLQBuEAJIEAZgHsAjJWp1GLXGIgSpshcpUAmTUMY4AvjhyhIsBIgAKAVwBGAG06LVqFCunFwAPPBITFAA5MRk0VAAPjEEIXzxAHwO4NARiADqUgAWKu7ArnQyRMDQaADyJFLhLlHR4pLScv7qCcltBh3G3WbRWdg4EAAeYCqIwFAcKhLz7i4AKioePpyBABSrSJR5AJRHLlu%20HN2oGRiieIvLGO1GXaZqUS%20dJqpmUQB0gMQEGoNkCB0QAG57lBgcB3IgCFAIdDsDYgA)

Comment: Your answer is perfect! Thank you.  Is there any way I could tell lodash or typescript itself to pick all the elements defined by the subtype? Like _.pick(User, UserPublicInfo). This would be much better than explicitly picking attributes defined by the subtype.

Comment: Btw, the last line of your example in the TS playground link was kind of broken, did you noticed too?